# Galaxy Tab 10.1 with unmodified Honeycomb (ie no TouchWiz)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I'm thinking about buying the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. It will have a modified version of Android Honeycomb (TouchWiz). Is it possible to install original Android from Google on it?

Comment: Has it been confirmed that the 10.1 will have touchwiz? i believe the ones handed out at I/O had Honeycomb 3.1, not touchwiz.

Comment: @Ryan Conrad Yes, the tablet has Honeycomb 3.1 and Touchwiz UI, just got a retail version yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As soon as someone unlock the bootloader(I don't know if they already done) someone will come up with a stock default theme ROM. You can stay tuned at [XDA-Developers](http://xda-developers.com/) for news about this.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible, as long as you can access the bootloader (ie. unlocked bootloader).